# Notation (confused) of set of (bi)linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't understand the difference between $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$ I need to find the dimension of these two vector spaces, I'll give that a go myself once I actually understand what im working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was taught in college:

- $\mathcal{L}(U, V)$ is the space of linear maps from $U$ to $V$ (here from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, called also linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$),
- $\mathcal{L}(U, V; W)$ is the space of bilinear maps from $U$ and $V$ to $W$;  be careful with the comma and the semicolon.

A quick reminder:

- linear maps: $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all $x, y \in U$, $a\in \text{field}$.
- bilinear maps are linear on each space separately:

  - $f(u+u', v) = f(u,v) + f(u',v)$, $f(au, v) = af(u,v)$,
  - $f(u, v+v') = f(u,v) + f(u,v')$, $f(u, av) = af(u,v)$,

  for $u, u'\in U$; $v, v'\in V$; $a \in \text{field}$.
  In other words: 
  $f(\cdot, v)$, $f(u,\cdot)$ are linear for all $v$, $u$ on $U$, $V$, respectively.